# Why isn't my inline-block span inheriting height?

Tags: html, css

My child element has a `height` of `20px` and the following CSS:

```
display: inline-block;
text-align: right;
width: 67px;
height: inherit;
```

[image]

The parent element has a `height` of `47px`.

[image]

Why isn't my element inheriting this height?

---

**HTML**

```
<div class='tango-directive-template'>

<div class='tango level-{{ level }}'>
  <span class='left-icons'>
    <img
      ng-show='tango.children.length > 0'
      src='/assets/images/show-arrow.png'>
    <span class='author'>A</span>
  </span>
  <textarea
    ng-focus='focus = true;'
    ng-blur='focus = false;'
    rows='1'>{{ tango.text }}</textarea>
  <p class='menu' ng-show='focus'>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-indent-left'></span>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-indent-right'></span>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down'></span>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right'></span.
  </p>
</div>

<tango
  ng-repeat='subtango in tango.children'
  tango='subtango'
  level='{{ +level + 1 }}'>
</tango>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tango-directive-template .tango {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.tango-directive-template .tango .left-icons {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 67px;
  height: inherit;
}
.tango-directive-template .tango .left-icons img, .tango-directive-template .tango .left-icons .author {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.tango-directive-template .tango .left-icons img {
  height: 20px;
}
.tango-directive-template .tango .left-icons .author {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.tango-directive-template .tango textarea {
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 700px;
  line-height: 135%;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  resize: none;
  border: 1px solid white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tango-directive-template .tango textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  overflow: auto;
}
.tango-directive-template .tango .menu {
  width: 750px;
}
.tango-directive-template .tango .menu span {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tango-directive-template .level-0 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
}
.tango-directive-template .level-1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 65px;
}
.tango-directive-template .level-2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 130px;
}
.tango-directive-template .level-3 {
  position: relative;
  left: 195px;
}
.tango-directive-template .level-4 {
  position: relative;
  left: 260px;
}
.tango-directive-template .level-5 {
  position: relative;
  left: 325px;
}
.tango-directive-template .level-6 {
  position: relative;
  left: 390px;
}
.tango-directive-template .level-7 {
  position: relative;
  left: 455px;
}
.tango-directive-template .level-8 {
  position: relative;
  left: 520px;
}
.tango-directive-template .level-9 {
  position: relative;
  left: 585px;
}
.tango-directive-template .level-10 {
  position: relative;
  left: 650px;
}
```

What I want is for the images to be centered vertically when the textarea resizes.

[image]

Comment: Hi Adam, I edited your title to optimize it for search (since this issue is more about inheritance than about a particular element). If you don't like the adjustment just restore the original.

Comment: @Michael_B I changed it back. Both the original and your revision specify inheritance. But the original also specifies that I'm dealing with an inline-block element, which is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit):

> The `inherit` CSS-value causes the element for which it is specified to take the [computed value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/computed_value) of the property from its parent element. It is allowed on every CSS property.

What you check in your developer tools is not the computed value, it is the so-called [used value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/used_value) which cannot be inherited.

To make a height inheritable, you need to **specify** it on the parent element.